# Bash script mounted as configmap with 777 permissions cannot be ran

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

This might be simple, but I can't seem to figure out why a bash script mounted as a configmap cannot be ran as root:

```
root@myPodId:/opt/nodejs-app# ls -alh /path/fileName 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Sep 10 09:33 /path/fileName  -> ..data/fileName

root@myPodId:/opt/nodejs-app# whoami
root

root@myPodId:/opt/nodejs-app# /bin/bash -c /path/fileName
/bin/bash: /path/fileName: Permission denied
```

I'm guessing, but I'd think that as with Docker, the root in the container isn't the actual root and works more like a pseudo-root account.

If that's the case, and the file cannot be ran this way, how would you include the script without having to re-create the Docker container every time the script changes?

Comment: It is worth noting that: /path/fileName is not a file you wanted to run but only a link to the file. The real file has quite different permissions and it is here: ls -l $(readlink -f /path/fileName). The default permission for a new file is 644, and that's why you cannot to execute the file.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

See here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/71356#issuecomment-441169334

You need to set the defaultMode on the ConfigMap to the permissions you are asking for:

```
volumes:
- name: test-script
  configMap:
    name: test-script
    defaultMode: 0777
```

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so I don't have links to the documentation, however the configmaps are definitely mounted on a ReadOnly filesystem. What I came up with is to cat the content of the file into another file in a location where the local root can write `/usr/local` in my case and this way the file can be ran.

If anyone comes up with a more clever solution I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score -7):

It's not surprise you cannot run script which is mounted as `ConfigMap`. The name of the resource itself (ConfigMap) should have made you to not use it.
As a workaround you can put your script in some git repo, then mount an EmptyDir into an InitContainer that clones the repo using git, then mount the EmptyDir into the Pod’s container. InitContainer will download the latest version every time during container creation

Comment: We're running a verison of Kubernetes where the InitContainers don't get re-ran when you recreate the pod, so you need to redeploy the whole deployment. I think I worked it out, though your approach looks like it would work too.

Comment: if you have too old version of Kubernetes, then it might support `GitRepo` Volume type, which is deprecated in the latest version.

Comment: Well thing is we're looking to update at some point, so we'll need a future-proof solution.

Comment: Your future-proof solution is to deploy CI/CD system, which will build images itself. It also could deploy apps to Kubernetes with zero downtime if your deployment settings will be correct.