# kubernetes - permission problem while starting a custom bash script

Tags: bash, shell, kubernetes, sh

I encountered an issue when initiating a bash script within an Ubuntu container, which led me to include the "bash" command to start the script in a new bash shell. The original command was:

```
command: ['sh', '-c', '/data/cleaner.sh']
```

However, I faced a "Permission denied" error, prompting me to modify the command to:

```
command: ['sh', '-c', 'bash /data/cleaner.sh']
```

The permission problem became evident in the container's output. The directory listing showed symbolic link details:

```
root@cleaner-58f6cd657-mzj5w:~# ls -l /data
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 Feb  6 18:45 cleaner.sh -> ..data/cleaner.sh
```

Attempting to execute the script directly resulted in a "Permission denied" error:

```
root@cleaner-58f6cd657-mzj5w:~# /data/cleaner.sh
bash: /data/cleaner.sh: Permission denied
```

On the other hand, using the modified command resolved the issue:

```
root@cleaner-58f6cd657-mzj5w:~# bash /data/cleaner.sh
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease [270 kB]
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
[...]
```

Additionally, here is the Kubernetes manifest, including the corrected command:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: cleaner-config
data:
  cleaner.sh: |-
    #!/bin/bash
    apt-get update
    apt-get install -y wget
    # some other commands...

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: cleaner
spec: 
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      ver: one9      
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        ver: one9
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: kontener
          image: ubuntu:latest
          command: ['sh','-c', 'bash /data/cleaner.sh']
          volumeMounts:
          - name: config
            mountPath: "/data/"
      volumes:
        - name: config
          configMap:
            name: cleaner-config
```

I'm intrigued why the script didn't start in the sh shell, but it did work in bash.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bash script mounted as configmap with 777 permissions cannot be ran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52254980/bash-script-mounted-as-configmap-with-777-permissions-cannot-be-ran)

Comment: Sure, it gave the explicit solution in the form of defaultMode config option; apart from that you prompted me to dig deeper, for which I sincerely thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost certainly the same issue as described in [Bash script mounted as configmap with 777 permissions cannot be ran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52254980/bash-script-mounted-as-configmap-with-777-permissions-cannot-be-ran)

Where a mounted script is showing as 777 but cannot be executed. Setting the `defaultMode` to something like `0755` or similar will work (I had this exact same problem on a project I was working on recently)

Comment: Thank you for you valued answer. I'd like to follow up the points you mentioned.

Comment: In my view, the script cleaner.sh itself doesn't have permission 777 as it is suggested but shows the permission of the symbolic link itself. The file cleaner.sh is created somewhere in space managed by Kubernetes and have quite different permissions, I mean 644. You can see this clearly here:
root@cleaner-6ff4c9bcbf-5w4x9:/data# ls -l $(readlink -f cleaner.sh)
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 730 Feb  8 09:19 /data/..2024_02_08_09_19_02.3631561511/cleaner.sh

Comment: Attempting to make it executable fails due to the mentioned read-only filesystem, likely the default in the case of ConfigMap.
root@cleaner-6ff4c9bcbf-5w4x9:/data# chmod +x /data/..2024_02_08_09_19_02.3631561511/cleaner.sh
chmod: changing permissions of '/data/..2024_02_08_09_19_02.3631561511/cleaner.sh': Read-only file system
However, introducing a new bash shell works, disregarding the lack of execute permission.
root@cleaner-6ff4c9bcbf-5w4x9:/data# bash /data/..2024_02_08_09_19_02.3631561511/cleaner.sh
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]

Comment: Applying configuration option: "defaultMode: 0777" really do the trick, thanks for lesson. It provides the file cleaner.sh with enough permission to start as intended. 
root@cleaner-5d595cd967-sfjmp:/data# ls -l $(readlink -f /data/cleaner.sh)
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 730 Feb  8 09:53 /data/..2024_02_08_09_53_27.3152841748/cleaner.sh

Comment: Have you tried `command: ['bash','-c', '/data/cleaner.sh']` instead?

Comment: I tried but it also failed. To sum it up I can see two solution:
1) apply defaultMode: -- with permission to execute the script
2) Invoke the script through bash, relying on the execute permissions of the Bash shell, not the script. This can be a workaround in situations where we can't directly modify the execute permissions of the script file due to filesystem restrictions